# некорректный запуск файла пайтон vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Столкнулся с проблемой, что когда запускаю код пайтон в vs code, он не запускается, даже не открывает терминал, но пробовал запускать сочетанием клавиш и выдает вот это:

```
command 'python.execInTerminal-icon' not found
```

И еще код запускается, когда открываю папку в самом vs code, и тогда все работает, но некорректно.